# How to display output of 'top' command on web browser using Php

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have a simple php script 'top.php' with shell_exec function.

Code:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("top");
?>
```

What I am looking for is to view results of 'top' command on a web browser. So, if I access http://192.168.1.1/top.php I want to see results of top command. It is essential to view results of top command periodically as you would see in a command line terminal.

However, when I access 'http://192.168.1.1/top.php' on web browser, it does not display anything. Same behaviour when I execute top.php on command line (as 'php top.php').

I am not sure what or where it is going wrong.....

Comment: could you do `var_dump(shell_exec("top"));` ? That way we'll know more like for example the return type

Comment: Perhaps `top` isn't exiting and returning output?  If I remember correctly, you might be able to do something like `top -n 1` or even `top -n 1 -b` to just get one page of output and exit.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107147#20109859) should answer your question (:

Comment: @FMashiro, var_dump(shell_exec("top")); produces same behaviour, i.e. script hangs, no output.

Comment: Well, script hangs is pretty different from having no output. If the page doesn't load, you may have to check the PHP logs on the server.

Comment: @David, Thanks, 'top -n 1' does show results of top command. Is there any way I can loop it endlessly? I need to see top command results on web browser periodically, say every 3 seconds.

Comment: @FMashiro, Sorry for typo. I meant, script does not produce any output.

Comment: I managed to progress few steps since yesterday. Got a new script that parses top command output (originally described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789444/parsing-output-of-top-command-shell-with-php). Code of new script:                                               <?php
    exec('./4.5.sh');
    sleep(10);
    $file = '/tmp/4.4.txt';
    $orig = file_get_contents($file);
    $a = htmlentities($orig);
    echo '<code>';
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $a;
    echo '</pre>'; 
    echo '</code>';
    ?>

Comment: However, /tmp/4.4.txt is created as empty file (file permission issue?), but isn't /tmp writable by all users? If I run php on command-line as root, 4.4.txt captures output of top command, and now if I access same php on browser I can see contents of 4.4.txt file. How to resolve this file permission/creation issue? It appears php script is executing fine once 4.4.txt file exists. Any alternative ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`top` on the command line by default just keeps running, so I suspect what's happening here is that it's not exiting and returning output to PHP.  The `-n 1` flag should address that:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("top -n 1");
?>
```

This would give you one "page" of output from `top` to display on your webpage.  In order to refresh it, you would of course just refresh the webpage.

To make something a little smoother (where you don't have to refresh the page), you could have a page which makes an AJAX request to this PHP script and then displays the output on the page.  That AJAX request could then be scheduled with `setInterval()` in JavaScript to occur ever X seconds as you see fit.

Comment: Good god, and I thought being a PHP novice is enough to get the job done ! :) Thanks for your detailed response, I will start looking into Ajax, JScript books.

Comment: If you want to display output on the browser by AJAX call, use the command as `top -b -n 1`